# Sort 2d array, which way is correct?

Tags: java, jgrasp

Im about to sort a 2d array. However there is a certain way of doing this. (Times of running it through, before proceeding to next row)

As you can see, what i've done here, is that im first sorting row 0, whereafter im incrementing! 
Before i increment the row, i let it sort the columns math.pow(m[j].length, 2).. Is this correct?

Furthermore, is there a smart way of printing out a 2D array from a void method, without using a for loop ?

```
  for (int j = 0; j < m.length; j++)
  {

    for (k = 0; k < math.pow(m[j].length, 2); INCREMENT++)
    {  
        for (int i = 0; i < m[j].length; i++)
        {

        if (m[i][j] > m[i + 1][j]) 
        {
           int temp = m[i][j];
           m[i][j] = m[i + 1][j];
           m[i + 1][j] = m[i][j]
        }
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting out of bounds?

Comment: oh yea. i got that error, its corrected however, so just disregard it.